# How to create a successive measures in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, average, dax, measure

I'm trying to create a three successive measures. In this case, I have two levels of grouping finding maximum, then the third level of grouping I'd like to have the average.  This needs to be a measure as I need to be able to slice the inputs of the aggregation.

I'm new to Power BI, so I may have not written the syntax correctly. I've tried various iterations of averagex, summarize, groupby etc.

All help is much appreciated!

Here is an example of the data I am working with:

`Name   uniqueID    Equipment_Number    Failure_Mode    Rating
A       A1          A1A                 Succcess        1
A       A1          A1A                 Low             2
A       A1          A1B                 Succcess        1
A       A1          A1B                 Success         1
A       A2          A2A                 Succcess        1
A       A2          A2A                 High            4
A       A2          A2B                 High            4
A       A2          A2B                 High            4

B       B1          B1A                 Succcess        1
B       B1          B1A                 Succcess        1
B       B1          B1B                 Succcess        1
B       B1          B1B                 High            4
B       B2          B2A                 Low             2
B       B2          B2A                 Success         1
B       B2          B2B                 Medium          3
B       B2          B2B                 Low             2`

I'd like to have three measures:

```
Three successive measures:
using the Rating Data from the table above
    Equipment_Number Max
    A1A  2
    A1B  1
    A2A  4
    A2B  4
    B1A  1
    B1B  4
    B2A  2
    B2B  3

   using the Equipment_Number max measure grouping by uniqueID
    uniqueID Max
    A1  2
    A2  4
    B1  4
    B2  3

    using the uniqueID max measure grouping by Name
    Name Average
    A  3
    B  3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you define a variable, it's a fixed value. I.e., `__Module_Rating_Measure` is fixed.

Then your second `VAR`, `__System_Rating_Measure` gives the same constant since every value you're maxing over is the same fixed value. Same for the average.

Try defining those `VAR` parts as separate measures rather than within the same measure as variables.

The other option would be to use `SUMMARIZE` to build table variables rather than scalar variables.

For more specific detail, it would help to edit your question to provide sample data and desired result.

---

**Edit:** I don't see any reason to take the max twice. Just take the max once at the `uniqueID` level and then average:

```
Average =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Table1[uniqueID] ),
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[Rating] ),
        Table1[uniqueID] = EARLIER ( Table1[uniqueID] )
    )
)
```

This iterates through each `uniqueID` value in the current filter context and calculates the maximum `Rating` for that ID and then takes the average.

[image: AvgMax]

Comment: Thanks so much Alexis!  I edited the question and gave some example data to better illustrate what I'm looking to do.  Many thanks!!!

Comment: Your answer works great  and really helps me better understand the DAX syntax.  Thank you so much for the help!